# How can a numpy array be created on a laptop when it's size exceeds system memory?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an 8gb Macbook Pro and if I create a numpy array like so, it tells me that it is 2Terabytes in size? I'm confused by this because I thought a numpy array allocated contiguous RAM. So how does this work?

```
array = np.zeros(1000000 * 1000000, dtype="int16")
In [28]: array.nbytes
Out[28]: 2000000000000
```

Comment: How big is your hard drive?  Could be in swap space.  Also, what were you expecting?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Hard Drive is 256gb with only 17gb free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The malloc implementation is playing tricks of you. Large chunks of reserved space are zeroed by the kernel due to security, and it is probably not actually giving them to you until you actually use them.

In my machine (Linux, 8GB RAM) the memory error has a lower threshold. This is supposed to allocate 6 GB of data:

```
arr = np.zeros(3000000000, dtype='int16')
```

As so does this:

```
arr2 = np.empty(3000000000, dtype='int16')
```

But the memory usage is the same. If you try instead to do

```
arr_ones = np.ones(3000000000, dtype='int16')
```

you will see memory usage blow up fast. And if you want to see your computer slowly cringing until it crashes, do this:

```
for i in xrange(len(arr)):
    arr[i] = 5
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the explanation I wanted.